# Eclipse unusably slow after upgrading MacOS from Catalina to Big Sur

Tags: eclipse, macos, performance, macos-catalina, macos-big-sur

I just upgraded MacOS from Catalina to Big Sur (all the way to 11.1) and now Eclipse is extremely slow. I have a handful of small projects in a workspace that was as snappy as you could desire when used in Catalina but now I get the beach ball when switching between two open tabs.

Launching, both Eclipse as well as projects, is also much slower, switching workspaces is slow and so on.

What I have tried:

1. Creating a new workspace and re-importing my projects.
2. Downloading a new version of Eclipse (I used to use 2020-09, downloaded 2020-12).
3. Launching it in clean mode. This produces a warning `WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.jpackage, jdk.incubator.foreign`.

Everything else works as expected after the upgrade. Computer is a Macbook Pro 16" with 6 + 6 cores i7 and 32 GB of RAM so it shouldn't struggle with the load.

Comment: 2020-09 had various problems on Big Sur but I don't think performance was one of them - certainly works OK for me (macOS 11.1, Oracle Java 15.0.1). But exactly what plug-ins are installed can make a big difference.

Comment: @greg-449 2020-09 and 2020-12 work similarly bad for me :-(

Comment: You could maybe try one of the minimal Eclipse downloads [here](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.18-202012021800/) and see if that has the performance issue (use a new workspace).

Comment: Same here. Did someone find a solution?

Comment: Second version of Big Sur released a couple of days ago doesn’t help. Also tried Eclipse 2021-03.M1 - same issue... Does someone have more info?

Comment: I realised my problem after a while. I use AppPolice to limit the CPU usage of certain applications (hello Thunderbird!) when in background. For some reason, AppPolice had applied a low limit on Eclipse. Furthermore, for the first few hours after the upgrade I think the issue was that Spotlight was updating its index. But the should go away after a couple of hours.

Comment: @d-b is it still ok? Is everything back to normal?  Does Eclipse performs « as usual »?

Comment: @BertrandRenuart Yes